# Exclude all folders with specified name on "Find in Path" in WebStorm

Tags: search, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to exclude from search results in "Find in Path" window **all folders** in the project with a name **"__tests__"**. (I know that there is a *file mask* option but looks like it works only with file names).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

please follow [IDEA-130905](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130905) and linked tickets for updates.

For now, I can suggest creating a custom scope in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes** with these folders excluded and using this scope in **Find in Path**